# How to make Gradle 2.x, Gradle 3.x, Gradle 4.x to run with Java 9?

Tags: gradle, java-8, java-9

When using Gradle 2.x, 3.x, and 4.x that only supports Java 8, the gradle runtime does NOT run. I just installed JDK 9 on my MAC and now Gradle 2.x does NOT run. **Any versions before 4.2.1**.

```
$ gradle
$
```

Nothing happens... How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://blog.gradle.org/java-9-support-update, Java 9 support for Gradle came to Gradle 4.2.1.

After installing Java 9, you will have it by default in your system:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    9.0.1, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_131, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

At this point, you need to find the Gradle executable and change the JAVA_HOME to point to your Java 8 version because you still have it installed. Change the binary to define the **JAVA_HOME** to point to the Version 8 version.

```
~ ⌚ 22:54:20
$ which gradle
/usr/local/bin/gradle

~ ⌚ 11:19:12
$ vim /usr/local/bin/gradle

#!/usr/bin/env bash

##############################################################################
##
##  Gradle start up script for UN*X
##
##############################################################################

JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
```

After this, Gradle will work again!

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.13
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-04-25 04:10:10 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     3b427b1481e46232107303c90be7b05079b05b1c

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
```

Comment: If you hacked into the `/usr/local/bin/gradle`, I think you also need to update `gradlew` script per project setup as well for `JAVA_HOME` setting.